# How to get the absolute path of the Jar file?

Tags: java, path, directory

I am trying to get the absolute path (as a String) of the directory where the jar file is located. The jar file is executed with an application from another directory.
For this example, let us assume I have a jar file called Test.jar and it is located in `C:\TestFolder\`. How do I get this full path `C:\TestFolder\`, not the path of the application executing the jar? I tried using the `System.getProperty("user.dir")` but this did not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file is not what you need?

Comment: Does your application know the name of the jar or do you mean the jar from which the application was loaded?

Comment: What are you actually trying to ***achieve*** by knowing that path?